# Python 3.3: Convert XML to YAML

Tags: python, xml, dom, yaml

I'm trying to convert XML files to YAML using Python 3.3.
This is my code:

```
#! /etc/python3

test_filename_input = './reference-conversions/wikipedia-example.xml'
test_filename_output = 'wikipedia-example_xml_read-as-binary.yaml'

file_object = open( test_filename_input, 'rb')
data_in = file_object.read()
file_object.close()

from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
document_object = parseString( data_in)

import yaml
stream = open( test_filename_output, 'w')
yaml.dump( document_object, stream)
stream.close()
```

As a reference I used the XML-file from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=JSON&oldid=622373984#XML_samples):

```
<person>
  <firstName>John</firstName>
  <lastName>Smith</lastName>
  <age>25</age>
  <address>
    <streetAddress>21 2nd Street</streetAddress>
    <city>New York</city>
    <state>NY</state>
    <postalCode>10021</postalCode>
  </address>
  <phoneNumbers>
    <phoneNumber type="home">212 555-1234</phoneNumber>
    <phoneNumber type="fax">646 555-4567</phoneNumber>
  </phoneNumbers>
  <gender>
    <type>male</type>
  </gender>
</person>
```

which should result in something like this:

```
---
  firstName: John
  lastName: Smith
  age: 25
  address: 
        streetAddress: 21 2nd Street
        city: New York
        state: NY
        postalCode: 10021

  phoneNumber: 
        -  
            type: home
            number: 212 555-1234
        -  
            type: fax
            number: 646 555-4567
  gender: 
        type: male
```

However, the result is:

```
&id001 !!python/object/new:xml.dom.minidom.Document
state: !!python/tuple
- implementation: !!python/object:xml.dom.minidom.DOMImplementation {}
- _elem_info: {}
  _id_cache: {}
  _id_search_stack: null
  childNodes: !!python/object/new:xml.dom.minicompat.NodeList
    listitems:
    - &id039 !!python/object/new:xml.dom.minidom.Element
      state: !!python/tuple
      - null
      - _attrs: null
        _attrsNS: null
        childNodes: !!python/object/new:xml.dom.minicompat.NodeList
          listitems:
          - &id045 !!python/object/new:xml.dom.minidom.Text
            state: !!python/tuple
            - null
            - _data: "\n  "
              nextSibling: &id002 !!python/object/new:xml.dom.minidom.Element
                state: !!python/tuple
                - null
                - _attrs: null
                  _attrsNS: null
                  childNodes: !!python/object/new:xml.dom.minicompat.NodeList
                    listitems:
[...]
```

Any idea, how to get PyYAML filter out the object-stuff from xml.dom.minidom or any alternative to using xml.dom.minidom?

Thanks!

Comment: XML is far more flexible and general than YAML, meaning that a lot of XML doesn't have a natural YAML equivalent. If you want a nice mapping for a specific case where there *is* an equivalence, you'll have to define and implement it yourself.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an approach that addresses the problems with xml.dom and provides an approach to map the ambiguous situation where a node has both content and attributes or children.  For the example input above it yields:

```
$ python3 yamlout.py person.xml
---
person:
  firstName: John
  lastName: Smith
  age: 25
  address:
    streetAddress: 21 2nd Street
    city: New York
    state: NY
    postalCode: 10021
  phoneNumbers:
    phoneNumber:
      _xml_node_content: 212 555-1234 
      type: home # Attribute
    phoneNumber:
      _xml_node_content: 646 555-4567 
      type: fax # Attribute
  gender:
    type: male
```

The implemention, yamlout.py:

```
import sys
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: {0} <file>.xml".format(sys.argv[0]))

XML_NODE_CONTENT = '_xml_node_content'
ATTR_COMMENT = '# Attribute'
def yamlout(node, depth=0):
    if not depth:
        sys.stdout.write('---\n')
    # Nodes with both content AND nested nodes or attributes
    # have no valid yaml mapping. Add  'content' node for that case
    nodeattrs = node.attrib
    children = list(node)
    content = node.text.strip() if node.text else ''
    if content:
        if not (nodeattrs or children):
            # Write as just a name value, nothing else nested
            sys.stdout.write(
                '{indent}{tag}: {text}\n'.format(
                    indent=depth*'  ', tag=node.tag, text=content or ''))
            return
        else:
            # json.dumps for basic handling of multiline content
            nodeattrs[XML_NODE_CONTENT] = json.dumps(node.text)

    sys.stdout.write('{indent}{tag}:\n'.format(
        indent=depth*'  ', tag=node.tag))

    # Indicate difference node attributes and nested nodes
    depth += 1
    for n,v in nodeattrs.items():
        sys.stdout.write(
            '{indent}{n}: {v} {c}\n'.format(
                indent=depth*'  ', n=n, v=v,
                c=ATTR_COMMENT if n!=XML_NODE_CONTENT else ''))
    # Write nested nodes
    for child in children:
        yamlout(child, depth)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as xmlf:
    tree = ET.parse(xmlf)
    yamlout(tree.getroot())
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if ":" are used in the xml-node-content. The indentation for xml-node-contents with multiple lines is not correct.

Comment: @Natan - multiline strings in YAML are a whole adventure in themselves.  But, you could change the one line above to `nodeattrs[XML_NODE_CONTENT] = json.dumps(node.text)` to address the immediate issue.

Comment: I think a safer solution - that allows multiline strings - is to create a dictionary and then yaml dump it.

Answer (score 3):

I found an [XML to YAML converter](http://svn.pyyaml.org/pyyaml-legacy/trunk/experimental/XmlYaml/convertyaml_map.py), but I had to make a minor change at about line 92:

```
outStr = yaml.dump(out)
```

changed to

```
outStr = yaml.safe_dump(out)
```

which removes any `!!python/unicode` tags in the output.  I have tested the script via shell command line and it works fine; I'm sure it's just a simple translation to get it to work within the Python command line.

**Edit**

I also added my own printing method to make the output look more like what you posted originally:

```
def prettyPrint(node, level):
childPrint = 0
attrPrint = 0

for x in node:
    try:
        if x['attributes']:
            attrPrint = 1

            for l in range(0, level):
                sys.stdout.write("\t")

            for a in x['attributes']:
                sys.stdout.write("- %s: %s\n" % (a, x['attributes'][a]))

    except KeyError:
        try:
            if x['children']:
                childPrint = 1

                for l in range(0, level):
                    sys.stdout.write("\t")

                sys.stdout.write("%s:\n" % x['name'])
                prettyPrint(x['children'], level+1)

        except KeyError:
            pass

    finally:
        if not childPrint:
            printNextNode(x, level, attrPrint)
            attrPrint = 0

        else:
            childPrint = 0

def printNextNode(node, level, attrPrint):
    for l in range(0, level):
        sys.stdout.write("\t")

    if attrPrint:
        sys.stdout.write('  ')

    sys.stdout.write("%s: %s\n" % (node['name'], node['text']))
```

This is then called within the `convertXml2Yaml` function:

```
sys.stdout.write('%s:\n' % out['name'])
prettyPrint(out['children'], 1)
```

Comment: This is a strange suggestion; tabs are not valid in YAML but prettyprint explicitly uses them.

Comment: Incidentally I started to try to write a more generic version of this and discovered a couple of things.  Modern pyyaml returns a dict, so the yaml2xml implementation of the script doesn't work.  Additionally python dicts of course cannot contain repetition and are not ordered, so cannot represent a lot of Yaml faithfully.  *sigh*

Comment: @jrodman XML can contain repetition, but in YAML you cannot repeat keys. So PyYAML dump can dump a Python dict to valid yaml, but you get the dict in alphabetical order, due to the normal dicts are not ordered and you loose the YAML order (and comments!) when going back from dict.

Comment: I am happy with roundtripping YAML / dict / YAML for documentation and looking up values (easy because of alpha order) but the use case depends. I was looking here for a quick listing of XML as YAML for readability. PyYAML can read JSON as well and XML to JSON 2 XML can be sometimes (not always) a symmetrical transformation as well. Getting the XML as YAML in proper order cannot be done using simple Python dicts. Keeping comments is the icing on the cake.

Comment: The source is gone but it is still on archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20160821015907/http://svn.pyyaml.org/pyyaml-legacy/trunk/experimental/XmlYaml/convertyaml_map.py

Answer (score 0):

Use https://pypi.org/project/yaplon/ -> https://github.com/twardoch/yaplon/

`xml22yaml -i "file.xml" -o "file.yaml"`

Doesn't support UTF-8 files with BOM though.