# Shell Scrip: split lines into array/YAML format with corresponding key and values

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell

Using: Shell Script

Please help to convert a file shown below, to an YAML format, which would like to use as `var` file for ansible playbook.

`file`: (it was actually a XML, i trimmed the header/footer and filter only required lines)

```
   <elementType>steering-pool</elementType>
   <attribute>
    <name>ip-address</name>
    <value>10.10.10.12</value>
   </attribute>
   <attribute>
    <name>start-port</name>
    <value>60</value>
   </attribute>
   <attribute>
    <name>end-port</name>
    <value>100</value>
   </attribute>
   <elementType>steering-pool</elementType>
   <attribute>
    <name>ip-address</name>
    <value>10.10.10.13</value>
   </attribute>
   <attribute>
    <name>start-port</name>
    <value>70</value>
   </attribute>
   <attribute>
    <name>end-port</name>
    <value>100</value>
   </attribute>
   <elementType>steering-pool</elementType>
   <attribute>
    <name>ip-address</name>
    <value>10.10.10.14</value>
   </attribute>
   <attribute>
    <name>start-port</name>
    <value>80</value>
   </attribute>
   <attribute>
    <name>end-port</name>
    <value>100</value>
   </attribute>
```

Number of elements may vary, for example above file has three and each element has `ip-address`, `start-port`, `end-port`.

i am struggling to write this information to a array like below.

```
steering-pool:
    ip-address:10.10.10.12 start-port:60 end-port:100
    ip-address:10.10.10.13 start-port:70 end-port:100
    ip-address:10.10.10.14 start-port:80 end-port:100
```

please suggest what's the best approach i could use to convert it into output shown above.

THANKS in Advance.

Comment: Use a tool like `xmlstarlet` to parse XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my approach but as each 'element' is not grouped into one XML element, it won't work the way you are wanting it to.
You've mentioned that you've trimmed out some lines, these may be helpful to produce a better solution.

I've enclosed everything in a 'data' element, which was required to make it a valid XML document.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <elementType>steering-pool</elementType>
    <attribute>
        <name>ip-address</name>
        <value>10.10.10.12</value>
    </attribute>
    ...
</data>
```

Then you can use this script to parse the XML and print a YAML file to stdout.
This sort of works, but the values are overwritten when an attribute name is re-used.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml
import xml.etree.ElementTree

tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
data = {'steering-pool': []}

d = {}
for attribute in root.findall('attribute'):
    d[attribute.find('name').text] = attribute.find('value').text
data['steering-pool'].append(d)

print(yaml.safe_dump(data, default_flow_style=False))
```

Output:

```
$ python parse.py
steering-pool:
- end-port: '100'
  ip-address: 10.10.10.14
  start-port: '80'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,, Yes, this has a flaw that it overrides output if we have same attributes repeated..

Comment: After seeing your answer, i have extended my search and found appropriate answer in below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54372414/8763301

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea of using yaml, xml.etree modules in python.